# Perl text filtering

Tags: perl, logging, text, filter, split

How can I filter this text on a log file:

> /servicios/busquedas?colecciones=29&orden=score&recursos=rango-1-20&query=%28%28%28texto%3A%28periodos+AND+contractuales%29%29+OR+%28title%3A%28periodos+AND+contractuales%29%29+OR+%28%28extra%3A%28periodos+AND+contractuales%29%29%5E0.5%29+OR+%28%28title%3A%28%22periodos+contractuales%22%7E15%29%29%5E5%29+OR+%28%28extra%3A%28%22periodos+contractuales%22%7E15%29%29%5E3%29+OR+%28%28texto%3A%28%22periodos+contractuales%22%7E15%29%29%5E3%29%29%29 tardo 0.115818977355957 (network 0.111818977355957)

To get only this:

```
periodos contractuales
```

I've done it with split methods but I can't find any regular character to split. The words `periodos and contractuales` are changing all the time!

Comment: Why 'filter' when it looks like all your interested in is whether the text 'periodos' and 'contractuales' exist.  Just look for those two words specifically.

Comment: @Drew the text periodos and contractuales is changing all the time!

Comment: Do the number of parameters change? this AND that AND the other or is it always exactly {someword} AND {otherword} ?  What about the 'AND', is ther ever an 'OR' ?

Answer (score 1):

When its only the `periodos` and the `contractuales` part, this should work:

```
if ( $string =~ m{periodos} && $string =~ m{contractuales}/ ) {
   print q{periodos contractuales};
}
```

Comment: the text periodos and contractuales is changing all the time

Comment: why did you dont wrote that in your question??